# Storing internal sound files at a place where I can access them via file paths in Android

Tags: android, audio

The standard way in Android seems to be to store Resources in `res/sound` or something similar. Then Android intervally produces a `R.sound.xxx` int that can be used to access the file.

I want to lot a few hundreds small sound files in my app and load the file names from the audio files via the SQLlite database. That means I can't rely on the `R.sound.xxx` int.
Where should I store my sound files and how do I access them?

At best I would want to use setDataSource so that I can play multiple files without having to create a new mediaplayer for every file.

Something like (however "file.mp3" doesn't work as a path):

```
public void prepareAudio(MediaPlayer mp, Context context) {

    try {
        mp.setDataSource("file.mp3");
        mp.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        mp.prepare();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "IllegalStateException for mediaplayer with file " + getAudioFileName(), e);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Can't read audio file " + getAudioFileName(), e);
    }
}
```

When I try (with the file `file.mp3` in folder res/raw):

```
public void prepareAudio(MediaPlayer mp, Context con) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Prepare audio start");

    try {
        int rawresid = con.getResources().getIdentifier("file.mp3",
                "raw", con.getPackageName());
        AssetFileDescriptor afd = con.getResources().openRawResourceFd(rawresid);

        mp.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(), afd.getStartOffset(), afd.getDeclaredLength());
        mp.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        mp.prepare();
        mp.start();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "IllegalStateException for mediaplayer with file " + getAudioFileName(), e);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Can't read audio file " + getAudioFileName(), e);
    }

    Log.d(TAG, "Prepare audio end");
}
```

I get the error:

```
09-01 18:23:08.590: W/ResourceType(15257): No package identifier when getting value for resource number 0x00000000

09-01 18:23:08.590: D/AndroidRuntime(15257): Shutting down VM
09-01 18:23:08.590: W/dalvikvm(15257): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41990d40)
09-01 18:23:08.600: E/AndroidRuntime(15257): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-01 18:23:08.600: E/AndroidRuntime(15257): Process: com.pairs.pairs, PID: 15257
09-01 18:23:08.600: E/AndroidRuntime(15257): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.pairs.pairs/com.pairs.pairs.TwoChoice}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can user your /res/raw folder, an access with Resources [getIdentifier](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getIdentifier(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) and then [openRawResource](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#openRawResource(int,%20android.util.TypedValue))

Example:

```
InputStream ins = getResources().openRawResource(getResources().getIdentifier("FILENAME_WITHOUT_EXTENSION",
            "raw", getPackageName()));
```

Edit:

To use MediaPlayer, you don't have to call openRawResource, just use only getIdentifier. Example

```
 MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this,getResources().getIdentifier("FILENAME_WITHOUT_EXTENSION",
                "raw", getPackageName()));
 mediaPlayer.start();
```

Edit 2:

try this:

```
int rawresid = getResources().getIdentifier("FILENAME_WITHOUT_EXTENSION",
            "raw", getPackageName());
AssetFileDescriptor afd = getResources().openRawResourceFd(rawresid);

mp.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(), afd.getStartOffset(), afd.getDeclaredLength());
```

Comment: Where do I put the file name into that call?

Comment: change FILENAME_WITHOUT_EXTENSION for the file name (without extension)

Comment: Tell me if you need help opening the file with MediaPlayer @Christian

Comment: Yes, at the moment I don't see how the InputStream helps me.

Comment: That works but I would prefer if I could use setDataSource, so I can reuse my media player. Unfortunately it doesn't accept the same arguments as the constructor.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60403/discussion-between-sirkuryaki-and-christian). @Christian